# Passing luks passphrase to unlock encrypted rootfs with script instead of passing from the terminal

Tags: command-line, scripts, encryption, luks, cryptsetup

I would like to develop a script which passes LUKS passphrase instead of passing from the keyboard when cryptroot asks user to unlock. I tried to modify cryptroot script, but not able to run it.

It would be great if I get any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd want to have a LUKS root and then store the passphrase and script its usage... Doing that essentially overrides the reasons for using a LUKS root.

You'd need to do a lot of work on:
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/local-top/cryptroot
Replace any code that sets up the variables holding the commands that prompt for the passphrase... Quite a bit of work.

It makes sense to use a scripted manner on other file-systems and removable media, but not root/initramfs/etc... Scripting it just seems to make a LUKS root unnecessary.

Good Luck!

Comment: I think so, in a simple way is it possible to replace the askpass executable with passphrase string inside cryptroot to decrypt root filesystem. I tried in different ways, everytime it is dropping into busy shell.  Thank you.